# CSS3 animation: Number Count Up?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a count-up animation using CSS3 that starts at a certain number "X" and counts up at a set interval by +1 using an animation sort of like [this](http://blog.daymedia.co.uk/2011/07/make-an-animated-counter-in-css3/).

I know its possible to use the animation-duration line as the animation length, and just set the animation-iteration-count to infinite, but is it possible to make it load as "X+1" on each restart of the animation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your in-progress code? We can help you debug what you already have, but we‘re not here to write your entire code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thorough solution with many CSS-only options for counters is [this](https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/)!

Answer (score 2):

It could maybe be done with a pseudo-element where you animate the content attribute, but support of CSS animations on pseudo-elements is still somewhat sketchy.

A JS-free solution would be to put the couting numbers actually in the HTML and then animate between those with

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(X);
```

Example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTj4E/1/)

Depending on your feelings towards extra markup I would probably go with a JS solution (there's plenty out there).